# Why school buses are not painted in red?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life

I came to know recently about why the road signals such as dead end signal or something like these have red paint because this colour's dispersion is very least among other rainbow colours.

But my question is why don't buses are red? I mean, I know yellow attracts the attention but red also disperses least in the surround and hence we will be then able to clearly see them while we are in traffic or when we need to figure out its dimensions. Like when we are driving car we need to give pass, then, due to red colour its edge dispersion will be lesser and image formed will be more sharp and it will be clearly visible from more distance.

Is my reason correct?

Comment: I think it's more a matter of tradition than anything having to do with physics.  The main thing is for the school bus to have a color that is easy to recognize as a school bus color.  Probably red, yellow, and blue stripes would work even better, but I'm glad they don't paint them that way!

Comment: But if it is about tradition. Here on Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_bus_yellow         
 there is a phrase $formulaed$ $in$ $a$ $conference$. If its being formulated by a science professor then he must have been knowing about red colour. Then also why only yellow?

Comment: Really, dispersion has very little to do with the issue. Big bus things that are yellow are school buses. Big fuzzy bus-like things are still school buses.

Comment: May I please know the reason for downvote?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to physics.

Comment: They are only yellow in the USA. In the UK for example there is no standard color, they are the same colour as the other buses in the company fleet. Some bus companies even have all-red bus fleets (London buses are the best known example, of course) since many emergency vehicles UK aren't red either.

Comment: At least one downvote is because dispersion has absolutely nothing to do with what color school buses are painted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red in the US is always associated with emergency equipment.

In 1939 the US actually formulated a color called "School Bus Yellow"   The color was chosen because it attracts attention and is noticed quickly in peripheral vision, faster than any other color. Scientists describe this as follows: "Lateral peripheral vision for detecting yellows is 1.24 times greater than for red."  (http://www.colormatters.com/color-matters-for-kids/why-are-school-buses-yellow)

Comment: Isn't somehow intrinsically "more bright"? Perhaps I am not choosing the right terms but I think is easy to see a yellow bus than a red one especially against urban environments and in scarce visibility conditions.